# Авто-тестирование сайта ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, юнит-тесты

Ситуация. Есть веб-приложение под IIS на классическом ASP.NET, .net 3.5.
В качестве слоя данных используются классы-сущности, в которых также лежат и методы обращения к базе, реализованные через чистый ADO.NET + хелперы (да, не самый лучший подход, но уж какой есть).
База данных -- SQL Server, многое реализовано через хранимые процедуры.
Система больше учётная, кое-где есть несложные расчёты.
В общем, навороченная долгоживущая легаси система.

Собственно вопросы:

- Классы-сущности лежат прямо в проекте сайта в папке App_Code. Каким образом можно поставить эти классы под юнит-тесты (обычно пользую NUnit)? При этом очень, очень не хочется затаскивать зависимость от юнит-тест-фреймворка прямо в проект сайта. Могу ли я сделать солюшен, вкючающий проект веб-сайта и проект юнит-тестов, и использовать классы-сущности из App_Code сайта в юнит-тестах?
- Какие ещё методы авто-тестирования стоит использовать в данном случае?

Переписать с нуля не предлагать. Объяснять, что сущности и методы доступа надо разделить -- тоже не надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема с App_Code в том, что эти файлы не компилируются как часть веб-проекта. Их компилирует ASP.NET при старте приложения.

Соответственно, тесты их не видят. И не увидят даже если вы добавите юнит-тесты прямо в веб-проект.

С точки зрения самого веб-проекта, и любого проекта тестов - эти файлы - просто Content (как и выставлено у них в свойствах в Build Action). Т.е. вызвать их из кода юнит-тестов будет проблематично.

Два варианта.

Первый:

- Переименовать папку App_Code -> Code.
- Пройтись по всем файлам, поменять у них Build Action с Content на Compile.
- Создать тестовый проект.
- Добавить в тестовый проект Reference на Web - после этого классы, объявленные в Code станут видны в тестах.
- Возможно (если будут проблемы) поменять namespace у классов в App_Code с Code на другой (иногда классы в неймспейсе Code не видят классов из Referenc-ов из-за костылей в компиляторе).

Второй

- Создать тестовый проект.
- Создать в тестовом проекте папку Code.
- Добавить в нее все файлы из App_Code в виде ссылок (Add Existing Item, выбрать файл, кликнуть на стрелке на кнопке Add, выбрать Add As Link).
- Добавить в тестовый проект те же референсы, что сейчас добавлены в веб.
- После этого классы из App_Code будут видны в тестах.

Первый способ чуть более правильный - он избавляет вас от корня проблемы - наличия App_Code. Второй (может быть) чуть более простой - т.к. не требует вообще никаких изменений в веб-проекте.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ -- от этого уже можно дальше танцевать. В App_Code довольно много кода, поэтому делать ссылки замучаешься, их же ещё и поддерживать придётся.

Comment: @nzeemin я просто был в точно такой же ситуации лет N назад. Обошлось переименованием App_Code -> Code, сменой Build Action и местами сменой неймспейса. так что удачи вам :)